# How do I return the value of a SignalR function to a parent function when the SignalR function is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

I have a SignalR function that retrieves some data from a hub.

Example:

```
var getApple = function () {
    hub.server.getFruits("Apple").done(function (result) {
        return result;
    });
};
```

I want to be able to return the value of `getFruits()` to `getApple()` when `getFruits()` is done;

```
console.log(getApple());
```

However using this approach, `getApple()` will always be undefined.

I've tried the following (really ugly) solution

```
var getApple = function () {
    var result2;
    hub.server.getFruits("Apple").done(function (result) {
        result2 = result;
    });
    return result2;
};
```

However `getApple()` was undefined until `getFruits()` was completed. I was able to workaround this with a `setTimeout()` but this is obviously a terrible solution.

I've also tried the following but this does not seem the return the actual result of `getFruits()`.

```
var getApple = function () {
    return hub.server.getFruits("Apple").done(function (result) {
        return result;
    });
};
```

From my understanding I'm lacking async javascript/jquery promise(?) knowledge. I've read the documentation and have looked at some other SO questions but was unable to properly place it into context.

I would greatly appreciate a code example of a proper implementation for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work - basically you need to create a promise object in a function like so:

```
    var callTestMethod = function() {
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var result = myHub.server.testMethod();
            resolve(result);
        });

        return promise;
    }
```

and this is how you call it and wait for the result:

```
    $.when(callTestMethod()).done(function(result) {
        alert(result);
    })
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you. :)